# Problems using VIM on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vim

Now that we have Ubuntu on Windows, I tried using VIM, but it seems to be utterly unable to recognize keyboard presses: after moving into insert mode, ordinary button presses do things completely unrelated to actually typing, like jumping around, deleting words, and generally acting in an unpredictable way.

Looking for any hints on how to fix this problem.

Comment: What is Ubuntu on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the latest updates to WSL have fixed the keyboard input issues.